# Logged User on LDAP get all details

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have done a connection to a LDAP server in Java using:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://XXX");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "DOMAIN\\user.name"); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
if(ctx != null){
    // get details : samaccount, mail, userprincipal, all fields from AD
}
```

I am a newbie in all computer languages, but in PHP I can define a filter using
a `samaccountname`(same as `user.name` in previous code) and that search returns
an associative arrays of all details of that user. How can I do this in Java?
Just using the `samaccountname`(user will enter just `user.name` value and his password), after bind is done ok and context is created
get all details of him.

Thanks in advance.

(PS: I didnt find anything on google that can help).

Answer (score 1):

You can provide search base and filter, here is an example:

```
String USER_SEARCH_BASE = "OU=somegroup,dc=company,dc=com";
String USER_SEARCH_FILTER = "(&(sAMAccountName=%username%)(objectclass=user))"
```

Then search the user in context:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://XXX");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "DOMAIN\\user.name"); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            if(ctx != null){
               String []requiredAttributes = {"sn","cn","sAMAccountName","memberOf"};
               SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
               controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
               controls.setReturningAttributes(requiredAttributes);
               SearchResult searchResult = null;
               NamingEnumeration user = ctx.search(USER_SEARCH_BASE, USER_SEARCH_FILTER, controls);
    while(users.hasMore()){
                searchResult=(SearchResult)users.next();
                Attributes attr = searchResult.getAttributes();
                String commonName = attr.get("cn").get(0).toString();
                System.out.println("Common Name: " + commonName);
               }

            }
```

Or you can debug the context and check all attributes available. 
Hope it was helpful.

Comment: @C.Constantin - You may like to accept the answer as well, if it helped you. See how to accept an answer -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work